# Can a non-resident Canadian citizen working in USA maintain a margin account in Canada?

Tags: united-states, stocks, canada, trading, non-resident

I am a non-resident Canadian living and working in USA. Can I maintain a margin account for stocks trading in Canada?

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea I removed the sentence requesting product/service recommendations.

Comment: I would like a definitive answer to this question too. A representative from Questrade told me that a non-resident of Canada may *not* maintain a margin account in Canada, adding that this is a SEC restriction. I also found the following quote on an Interactive Brokers forum: `Because of SEC restrictions, US legal resident customers are not allowed to trade non-US stock and cash index options.`, but it's not clear whether this applies to Canadian citizens.